# Preloader issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am still a newbie at most of this web stuff but I was trying to get a div to load before the website, cycle through the div's I created, then load the website. Here is my code below to cycle through and get the correct div:

```
$(function () {
$('#splash-holder').delay(6000).toggle('#splash-main');

var counter = 0,
    divs = $('#splash-one, #splash-two, #splash-three, #splash-five');

function showDiv () {
    divs.hide() // hide all divs
        .filter(function (index) { return index == counter % 3; }) // figure out correct div to show
        .fadeIn('fast'); // and show it

    counter++;
}; // function to loop through divs and show correct div

showDiv(); // show first div    

setInterval(function () {
    showDiv(); // show next div
}, 13 * 180); // do this every 10 seconds    

});
```

Then I use this preloader script:

```
$(window).load(function() {
 $('#preloader').delay(6000);
 $('#preloader').fadeTo('fast', 0.1 , function() {
 $('body').css('overflow','visible');
 $(this).remove();
 });
});
```

Here is my Code:

```
<div id="preloader">
  <div id="spinner_container">
    <div id="splash-holder">
      <div id="splash-title" class="hFont">We <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/logo-c.png" /></div>
      <div id="splash-one" class="hFont">conversations not messages.</div>
      <div id="splash-two" class="hFont">bridges not silos.</div>
      <div id="splash-three" class="hFont">things differently.</div>
 </div><!-- #splash-holder -->
   </div><!-- #spinner-container -->
 </div><!-- #preloader -->
```

This works, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner way of coding this.

Comment: This would be better suited under the js tag than php. And as an answer: you should first load the website (the browser law) and then modify the div while the rest of the page is hidden.

Comment: Removed the PHP tag. Nothing in this question is PHP.

Comment: What would be the best way to achieve what I am trying to do. Any help would greatly be appreciated. I know Khael said to load the website then modify the div while the rest of the page is hidden. Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to load a div before the page. The almost optimal solution is yours. You can't load a div before the page because the div is part of the DOM like the rest of your code. You can hide all the page with the exception of one div and wait the page to load while showing a loading bar ( if this is what you are trying to do ), but load a sequential page is possible just by ajax.

The ajax way would be to load only the page with the script and a loading bar and then build the page from a json received by ajax or load an entire viewport behind the loading bar "screen".

Have fun implementing it, it is quite a lot of code.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up khael. I guess I will try what you said, it would be best if I hide all the page with the exception of one div.